# how do I compare the string in a1 to the string in a2 to see which is bigger?

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

Write a static method named joiner that accepts two arrays of strings a1 and a2 as parameters and returns a new array a3 such that each element of a3 at each index i stores a new string composed of the words stored at a1[i] and a2[i] joined together with the word with the work having greater length (more characters) at the front of the concatenated string.  If there is a tie, take the element from a1.

For example, if a1 and a2 store the following elements:

```
String[] a1 = {"star", "pie", "jelly bean", "car"};
String[] a2 = {"cookie", "fig", "banana", "soda"};
```

Then your method should return the new array:

```
{"cookiestar", "piefig", "jelly beanbanana", "sodacar"}.
```

This is what i got so far:

```
for(int i = 0; i <length; i++) {
    if(a1[i].stringlength()<  a2[i].stringlength()) {
        String[] a3 = a1[i] + a2[i];
    }
    else {
        if(a2[i].stringlength().compareTo[i].stringlength() < 0) {
            String[] a3 = a2[i] + a1[i];
        }
        else {
            String[] a3 = a1[i] + a2[i];
        }

        return a3[i];
    }
}
```

Alot of errors but i tried alot of different things and cant seem to figure it out
. I'm trying to figure out how to compare the strings in both arrays by the index. How would I compare a1[i] and a2[i] to see which string is bigger? And how would assign both strings to a new array a3?

Comment: Please ask a *specific* question relating to a *specific* problem with the code - "please fix and complete my program" isn't a valid question.

Comment: sorry about that I rushed this question. Its in java. I'm trying to figure out how to compare the strings in both arrays by the index. How would I compare a1[i] and a2[i] to see which string is bigger? And how would assign both strings to a new array a3?

Comment: Just need hints to help myself figure it out. I just put the question since its hard to explain any other way

Comment: You would do, eg, `a1[i].length() > a2[i].length()`.

Comment: It helps if you actually look at the documentation for String so you can see that the `length()` method returns string length.

Comment: `if(a2[i].stringlength().compareTo[i].stringlength() < 0)`. What exactly is `compareTo` doing here? If anything at all.

Comment: what do you mean by "bigger"? Longer string is bigger?

Answer (score 2):

The question does not specify if the two arrays of strings `a1` and `a2` are always the same length, and if not what to do when they are not, however with that in mind the following code works for when they are equal in length:

```
public static String[] joiner(String[] a1, String[] a2) 
{
        int length1 = a1.length;
        int length2 = a2.length;
        String[] a3 = new String[length1];

        if( length1 == length2) {
            for( int i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
                if( a1[i].length() >= a2[i].length()) 
                    a3[i] = a1[i].concat(a2[i]);
                else
                    a3[i] = a2[i].concat(a1[i]);
            }
        }

        return a3; 
}
```